# How to create the get method for the call

Tags: php, arrays, json, http, quickblox

I am studying and implementing an api and while following the examples,

**Here is the example 1 :**

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0" \
-d '{"application_id": "2", "auth_key": "DtF9cZPqTF8Wy9Q", "timestamp": "1333630580", "nonce": "1340569516", "signature": "13293a5bd2026b957ebbb36c89d9649aae9e5503", "user": {"login": "injoit", "password": "injoit"}}' \
https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
```

**For the above example i consructed my get method as**

```
https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?token=re8d22c6e617133ffeadd761193a6c57d87bfb1a0f&application_id=23995&auth_key=CbRasu4Wftu25Qw&nonce=8796&timestamp=1434446627&signature=667ee2b448a5d3dd57d112afef3f84dd6c67e165
```

and it is working good.

But for the below example

```
curl -X POST \
-H "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0" \
-H "QB-Token: 17f6a337b0656c9c7e983f9705d79562fc694c0e" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"push_token": {"environment": "production", "client_identification_sequence": "aa557232bc237245ba67686484efab"},
"device": {" platform": "iOS", "udid": "5f5930e927660e6e7d8ff0548b3c404a4d16c04f"}}' \
http://api.quickblox.com/push_tokens.json
```

How can i create the get method. As this has two main arrays i am little confused.

**Can anyone help in creating how can i use this call ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
https://api.quickblox.com/push_tokens.json?push_token[environment]=production&push_token[client_identification_sequence]=aa557232bc237245ba67686484efab&device[platform]=iOS&device[udid]=5f5930e927660e6e7d8ff0548b3c404a4d16c04f
```

Comment: Thanks i can see that from the example itself `-d "push_token[environment]=production&push_token[client_identification_sequence]=aa557232bc237245ba67686484efab&device[platform]=iOS&device[udid]=5f5930e927660e6e7d8ff0548b3c404a4d16c04f" \` from here http://quickblox.com/developers/Messages#Create_subscriptions_.28subscribes.29

Comment: But whenever i do that, i am getting the same error `{"code":null,"message":"Resource not found"}` For your information, We are not sending the `token` along the param. Is that the issue ?

Comment: Hi, I tried with adding the token in additional to the url you provided, its is not working stilll....

Comment: I am receiving nothing except this error `{"code":null,"message":"Resource not found"}`

Comment: But, why do you need GET method? QuickBlox only supports POST for this API

Comment: Thanks i tried in post method i am getting error **{"code":null,"message":"No device registered for current user session. Device is obligatory to be able to execute actions with push token."}** What is the reason for this ?? Here is the Screenshot http://i.imgur.com/vVjKRxU.png

Comment: How can i register a device in user session ? I am trying those from Postman Client \

Comment: You have to use push_token[environment] instead of just environment. The same for all parameters

Comment: Even after i use push_token[environment] instead of just environment. It gives me the same error **{"code":null,"message":"No device registered for current user session. Device is obligatory to be able to execute actions with push token."}**

Comment: Here's the screen http://i.imgur.com/KH9Aqbg.png Should i do anything rather than it ? The token i entered is the one which  i used to login from web. Is that matter ?

Comment: I said you have to use the same format for ALL params: environment->push_token[environment], platform->device[platform], etc. Got it?

Comment: Look at my example above in answer

Comment: Thanks, I got the point, now i can able to have the push_token and subscriptions example .. Thanks for helping :)